# The Route line is not showing in android by using FeatureCollection

Tags: react-native, mapbox, polyline

I need your help in little bit query,
i'm trying to render the multiple polyline on a single map,it look like as it (IOS),
[image]
it perfectly fine work fine in IOS but not work in android, so my code Snippet it,

```
import MapboxGL from '@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps';
const MapbBoxDirection = ({shape}: any) => {
  const sp = returnOption(shape);
  const Poliline = React.useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <MapboxGL.Animated.ShapeSource
        id="routeSource"
        buffer={512}
        tolerance={1}
        lineMetrics={false}
        clusterRadius={10}
        shape={sp}>
        <MapboxGL.Animated.LineLayer
          id="routeFill"
          style={{
            lineColor: '#ff8109',
            lineWidth: 10,
            lineRoundLimit: 12,
            lineCap: 'round',
            lineOpacity: 1.84,
          }}
        />
      </MapboxGL.Animated.ShapeSource>
    );
  }, [shape, sp]);
  return Poliline;
};

import {featureCollection, lineString as makeLineString} from '@turf/helpers';
```

///// Make Json

```
export const returnOption = (res): any => {
  const feature = res.map((item: any, index: any) => {
    if (item[`Route${index}`]?.length > 2) {
      return makeLineString(item[`Route${index}`]);
    }
  });
  const featureCollectiondata = featureCollection(feature);
  return featureCollectiondata;
};
```

it's work fine in IOS but not work in android,

i'm also trying to make a json manually without truf helper, i'm facing same problem.
So would you please help me How i can resolve it for android,
one more thing is SINGLE route work fine for both platform so when i'm trying to use featurecollection json it create problem,
Please I'm very Thankful to you,

Comment: Did you test on android device?

Comment: Yes but it's not working. line is not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot a effort i got the Solution Sometime undefined and null is generate default Therefor route line not render on android, but ios it will handle it by default So

```
export const returnOption = async (res: any, setShape: any) => {
  const feature = await Promise.all(
    res.map(async (item: any, index: any): Promise<any> => {
      if (item[`Route${index}`]?.length > 1) {
        // return makeLineString(item[`Route${index}`]);
        return {
          type: 'Feature',
          properties: {
            prop0: 'value0',
            prop1: 0.0,
          },
          geometry: {
            type: 'LineString',
            coordinates: item[`Route${index}`],
          },
        };
      }
    }),
  );
  const RemoveUndefined = feature?.filter(item => item !== undefined);
  setShape({
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: RemoveUndefined,
  });
};
```

finally I have achieve the solution.